# Scale Image with Center crop by maintaining Aspect Ratio using CSS

Tags: html, css, image, responsive-design, scale

I want to create Image gallery like Mobile gallery . each Image should be in square box inside main container.

Image shouldn't be stretched instead crop or clip at maximum. 
now i stretch image with aspect ratio using this code,

```
img {
  max-width : 150px;
  max-height : 150px;
}
```

it gives me minimized thumbnail of each image. but i want to make all inside square box with center clipped or cropped image.

here is the example i want, 
[image]

Comment: `object-fit` with JS polyfill for older browsers, or `background-size` ...

Comment: thanks @CBroe object fit cover works what i want

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Here is the solution how i achieved it... it keeps aspect ratio and bring image into center as like what i want...

```
.scale-image {
  object-fit: cover;
  width: 150px;
  height: 150px;
}
```